# How to stop YouTube HTML5 video auto-loading (prefetching)

Tags: youtube, html5

I'm looking for a way to stop YouTube from automatically loading or prefetching HTML5 videos in my browser (Chrome 43).

I tried to use the "Stop YouTube HTML5 Autoplay" extension but It doesn't do that. I've seen similar questions in this website but they were all about how to disable HTML5 video completely. I only don't want YouTube (and if possible other websites) load HTML5 videos before I press the play button.

Comment: Advertisers wouldn't like that...

Comment: Well that's their problems. users care for their bandwidth. it's really stupid when you see a 5min HD video has been loaded and is only waiting for you to click play while you just wanted to read the comments for that youtube video. if this is the future of online videos then we all should miss the old flash-based youtube videos.

Comment: Question already answered here : http://superuser.com/questions/1038968/how-to-block-disable-all-videos-from-automatically-loading-in-chrome