# Does YouTube stop loading frames when in another tab?

Tags: youtube

I know that YouTube will play audio while in another tab or window, but my question:

(a) Does YouTube stop loading frames while in another tab? (i.e., loads audio but not video)
(b) If not, can I make it do as such?

I'm not picky if it buffers for a sec when I tab back, the video will be over anyways.

**Clarification:** I want to save bandwith by preventing Youtube from loading frames while unfocused. I suspect the answer is something like this psuedo-userscript:

```
 Every few (say, 5) seconds:  
   if the window is unfocused:  // Know this is possible; several JS games do things like this to save CPU time drawing things
      Tell youtube to stop loading frames
   else:
      Tell youtube to start loading frames
   fi
 yrevE
```

**EDIT:** If Youtube already does this (which it ought to), there is no problem.

Comment: Whether it stops loading or not seems easy enough to find out for yourself.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be obvious. Perhaps it loads low-quality when unfocused and starts loading higher quality when you focus the tab, and hence plays a few low-quality frames and you don't notice...

Comment: Perhaps if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve. Are you trying to save bandwidth by ensuring YouTube doesn't download video you're not watching?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! I'll edit the question

Comment: There are other similar questions here ([example](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80004/)) but I don't know that there's a good answer.

Comment: Yeah, related-but-not-quite-a-dupe.